# Event handling in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, events, event-handling

I am building an android app, I have a main view which responds to on touch events which cause the GUI to redrawn itself. I also have to redraw the GUI when certain network events occur. I have a separate thread listening on a socket. Currently i have the the network thread redraw the GUI rather than the GUI thread do it. This seems to be ok since redrawing the GUI is predictable.

However there is a scenario where i will get a message from the network which requires a redraw BUT it requires a user input BEFORE the redraw can be done. I am hesitant to let the network thread do this now as if the user doesn't input quickly the network thread will be stuck waiting for that input rather than listening for further communication.

The solution it would seem is to get the network event to fire an event when this scenario occurs and then GUI thread can listen to it like it listens to onTouch events.

1) how do i implement this?

A few other things

2) It possible to trick android into thinking an onTouch event has occur when it actually hasn't

3) when a button on a GUI fires an event which thread executes the onAction method. is is the GUI thread or does the button exist in its own thread.

Answer (score 0):

**-** You can use `java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch`.

**-** You can wait for the scenario to happen and when its done let GUI thread can start doing its work.